# Trouble with Negamax game of Nim

Tags: c, artificial-intelligence, negamax

I'm taking my first AI class and attempting to implement the NegaMax algorithm into my code in c. I am using this algorithm to play the simple game of Nim, where each player removes 1-3 matches on their turn. The computer plays against itself here. However, I'm having trouble with the implementation. So far, I cannot seem to get the state to change for each recursive call of the function. I get an infinite loop where the best value goes from -INFINITY to INFINITY (where infinity is 999999). So the program never terminates because the state never gets to 1.  I have trouble with recursion in general so if anyone can give me some hints as to where I should go with my code it would be greatly appreciated.

```
typedef struct State{
   int m;
   int eval;
}State;


State negaMax2(int state, int turn, State *best){
int move;
/*terminal state?*/
if(state == 1){
    printf("Terminal state\n");
    best->eval = turn;
    return *best;
}
best->m = -INFINITY;
for(move = 1; move <= 3; move++) {
    if (state - move > 0) { /* legal move */
     int value = -1 * (negaMax2(state-move, turn, best)).m;
     if (value > best->move){
         best->eval = turn;
         best->m = value;
     }
    }
  }
return *best;
}


void playNim(int state) {
int turn = 0;
State *best;
best->eval = turn;
while (state != 1) {
  int action = (negaMax2(state, turn, best)).m;
  printf("%d: %s takes %d\n", state, 
       (turn==MAX ? "Max" : "Min"), action);
  state = state - action;
  turn = 1 - turn;
  }
 printf("1: %s looses\n", (turn==MAX ? "Max" : "Min"));
}
```

Comment: Would prolog be a better choice of language?

Comment: @DelaneyWarren, are you sure that the `move` within `negaMax2()` is different than the one in the struct?

Comment: @CodingBatman yeah it's definitely different. Although thank you for pointing that out because it is a bit unclear. I've changed it now for readability.

Comment: And @EdHeal Because it's a class given in c, I unfortunately don't really have much choice on the language used.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  un-indent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with a variable width font.

Comment: This is literally my homework right now, lol. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is this:

```
State *best;
best->eval = turn;
```

You are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) here.  You are trying to access `eval` while `best` has not yet been initialised (it is just declared).

You should consider doing something along the following lines:

```
State best;
best.eval = turn;
```

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Thank you! That helps one of the problems I was having.